# How to increment a string by one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.2.7.  I have a string

```
possible_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_$1234567890 &*"
```

and I want to write a function that will increment a string, consisting only of chars of the above string, by one.  That is, if I have

```
str = "AA"
increment_by_one("AA")
```

`increment_by_one` would produce

```
AB
```

and similarly having a string

```
str = "**"
increment_by_one("**")
```

would produce

AAA

How can I write such a function?

Comment: Examples are fine, but you must first state your question fully. Are you saying that a string ending with `possible_chars[i]`, when `i < possible_chars.size - 1`, should be the same string with the last character replaced by `possible_chars[i+1]`? If `i` equals `possible_chars.size - 1` (`"*"`), I presume the next character is obtained by wrapping around, but it's still not clear. If `possible_chars = "0123456789"`, one would expect the string "99" to be followed by "100". That suggests to me that `"**"` should be followed by `"BAA"`, not `"AAA"`. Please clarify with an edit.

Comment: I stick by my statement -- "**" when incremented by one in my realm should be "AAA", then "AAB", "AAC" ... "***", then "AAAA".  In your sequence, you could never get to a string that is "000", which is the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: When asking, we want to see evidence of your effort in one of two ways: Did you search for solutions? If so, why didn't those pages help? Or, did you write code? If so, see "[mcve]". If not, why? Without that evidence we have to decide whether you're asking for us to write it for you, which isn't what SO is for. "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" discuss this. You've only given us requirements, which leans toward wanting us to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def next_str(str, possible_chars)
  ndx = possible_chars.index(str[-1])
  str[0..-2] +
  case ndx
  when possible_chars.size-1
    possible_chars[0]*(str[/[#{str[-1]}]+\z/].size + 1)
  else
    possible_chars[ndx+1]
  end
end

next_str("BC", possible_chars)
  #=> "BD" 
next_str("BC***", possible_chars)
  #=> "BC**AAAA"
```

In the second example, `/#{str[-1]}+\z/` would evaluate to `/*+\z/` which raises the exception

```
/#{str[-1]}+\z/ RegexpError: target of repeat operator is not specified: /*+\z/
```

That's because `"*"` has special meaning in the regex. I therefore put it in a character class, where it does not have special meaning.

Comment: Hey this was working great but then I noticed something.  If all possible_chars spans the alphabet e.g. ("ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRTSTUVWXYZ"), then next_str("AZ") should yield "BA", but with the above, it is giving "AAA".

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace only the last character of the string, here replacing `"Z"` (in `"AZ"`) with `"AA"`, returning `"AAA"`.